# Linking libusb-1.0 to mycfile.c fails

Tags: linker, libusb

Despite downloading and compiling libusb-1.0 to /usr/local, to know exactky where it is, gcc still can't find it;

```html
gcc -o usb -L/usr/local/lib -llibusb-1.0.so -I/usr/local/include myusbcfile.c
```

gives;

```html
usbtest.c:4:15: error: storage size of ‘brd_ftdi’ isn’t known
libusb_device brd_ftdi;
^
usbtest.c:5:22: error: storage size of ‘brd_ftdi_handle’ isn’t known
libusb_device_handle brd_ftdi_handle;
^
usbtest.c:6:16: error: storage size of ‘context’ isn’t known
libusb_context context;
^
```

This clearly indicates gcc can't find the library, tried different forms of this command, everyone giving this error.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is this one :

-lxxxx tells the linker : 'find a library called libxxxx', so what you're asking in your command line is to find the library `liblibusb-1.0.so`

Maybe you should try this :

`gcc -o usb -L/usr/local/lib -lusb-1.0.so -I/usr/local/include myusbcfile.c`

This way, the linker should be looking for a library called `libusb-1.0.so`

Comment: Did that. Have also tried add -Wall and sometimes -std=c99 sometimes -std=c11, still same error message.